# setOnClickListener() doesn't work

Tags: java, android, button

I have my MainActivity and a LoginActivity. I can call each method without any problem, but as soon as I try to click on the button "btnLogin" or "btnLinkToRegister", nothing happens.

LoginActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.test.music.myapplication.MainActivity;
import com.test.music.myapplication.R;
import com.test.music.myapplication.app.LoginConfig;
import com.test.music.myapplication.app.LoginController;
import com.test.music.myapplication.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import com.test.music.myapplication.helper.SessionManager;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity{
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_fragment);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        /*btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });*/

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    public void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                LoginConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        LoginController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    public Button getBtnLogin() {
        return btnLogin;
    }

    public Button getBtnLinkToRegister() {
        return btnLinkToRegister;
    }

    public void setBtnLogin(Button btnLogin) {
        this.btnLogin = btnLogin;
    }

    public void setBtnLinkToRegister(Button btnLinkToRegister) {
        this.btnLinkToRegister = btnLinkToRegister;
    }



    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

LoginFragment

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.test.music.myapplication.activity.LoginActivity;
import com.test.music.myapplication.activity.RegisterActivity;
import com.test.music.myapplication.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import com.test.music.myapplication.helper.SessionManager;

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    LoginActivity Log = new LoginActivity();


    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public LoginFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static LoginFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Log.getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

login_fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.music.myapplication.LoginFragment"
    android:background="@color/bg_login"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_login" />

        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

logcat

```
06-08 14:47:56.703 18829-18829/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-08 14:47:56.734 18829-18829/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
06-08 14:47:56.766 18829-18829/app.myapplication W/ActivityThread: Application app.myapplication is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-08 14:47:56.769 18829-18829/app.myapplication I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
06-08 14:47:56.958 18829-18835/app.myapplication I/art: Debugger is active
06-08 14:47:56.971 18829-18829/app.myapplication I/System.out: Debugger has connected
06-08 14:47:56.971 18829-18829/app.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-08 14:47:57.171 18829-18829/app.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-08 14:47:57.371 18829-18829/app.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-08 14:47:57.571 18829-18829/app.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-08 14:47:57.772 18829-18829/app.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-08 14:47:57.972 18829-18829/app.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-08 14:47:58.172 18829-18829/app.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-08 14:47:58.372 18829-18829/app.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
06-08 14:47:58.572 18829-18829/app.myapplication I/System.out: debugger has settled (1478)
06-08 14:47:58.585 18829-18829/app.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.myapplication-1/lib/arm64
06-08 14:47:58.700 18829-18829/app.myapplication V/BoostFramework: mAcquireFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])
06-08 14:47:58.700 18829-18829/app.myapplication V/BoostFramework: mReleaseFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()
06-08 14:47:58.700 18829-18829/app.myapplication V/BoostFramework: mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
06-08 14:47:58.700 18829-18829/app.myapplication V/BoostFramework: mIOPStart method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
06-08 14:47:58.700 18829-18829/app.myapplication V/BoostFramework: mIOPStop method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()
06-08 14:47:58.704 18829-18829/app.myapplication V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@f8b3883
06-08 14:47:58.704 18829-18829/app.myapplication V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@1d12a00
06-08 14:47:58.704 18829-18829/app.myapplication V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@cdb1239
06-08 14:47:58.704 18829-18829/app.myapplication V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@9ea507e
06-08 14:47:58.803 18829-18829/app.myapplication V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@11983e3
06-08 14:47:58.803 18829-18829/app.myapplication V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@29e81e0
06-08 14:47:58.835 18829-18829/app.myapplication D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {}
06-08 14:47:58.889 18829-18971/app.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-08 14:47:58.910 18829-18829/app.myapplication D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
06-08 14:47:58.996 18829-18971/app.myapplication I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : a7823f5, I59a6815413
                                                                               Build Date                       : 09/23/16
                                                                               OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.07.00.00
                                                                               Local Branch                     : mybranch22028469
                                                                               Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BR.1.3.3_rb2.26
                                                                               Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                               Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
06-08 14:47:59.030 18829-18971/app.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-08 14:47:59.072 18829-18971/app.myapplication E/HAL: hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
06-08 14:47:59.072 18829-18971/app.myapplication E/HAL: hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
06-08 14:48:02.796 18829-18829/app.myapplication W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
06-08 14:48:03.830 18829-18829/app.myapplication W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
```

If you need any more code, just let me know.

Comment: show xml please .

Comment: You could add some logs too

Comment: are you getting any error in your console ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I added the xml fragment
mrid  No, sadly not.

Comment: @Damet could you share logcat

Comment: @Damet, is the btnLogin.setOnClickListener for both buttons written in Activity ? if yes then kindly move it to fragment class respectively ?

Comment: Put a Log statement immediately within onClick, then tell us nothing happens... If that's the case, you're looking at the wrong Activity

Comment: @Damet you call your activity fragment ? or you call a View(Widget) a Fragment ?

Comment: You have a problem to writing

Comment: @Damet You write Your java code in Login Fragment.java file then Your code will work and Your Problem will Resolve

Comment: @Ashish There is code written in that file... What are you suggesting?

Comment: @Damet I am suggest You write fragment code in Fragment Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write Edit Your Fragment Class

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
  public  Button btnLogin;
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment,container,false):

btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Write this Way is Helping Too Much in Login Fragment .xml

Comment: I'm sorry, but I dont really understand what you are trying to explain to me. :-(

Comment: I think I understood it now but there I face the problem that the Fragment doesnt know my checklogin method from the LoginActivity class and getApplicationContext is still unknown.

Comment: @Damet This is Not a Perfect Code I am Giving You Idea How can You write Your Fragment java code.
If You Not Understand Then I am Send Perfect code that You have Required

Comment: well then it seems like I haven't understood everything from your example.

Comment: @Damet Hey What Happen My Code Is Helps You PleaseUpvote My Code

Comment: @Damet Now You Are able To Upvote Please Upvote My Answer

Comment: Did it. I already used to make it the most useful answer before.

Answer (score 1):

First off, never do this... Calling `new` on an Activity

```
LoginActivity Log = new LoginActivity()
```

Secondly, are you sure you're using Fragments?

This is an Activity

```
LoginActivity extends Activity
```

And you simply are putting the Fragment layout into the Activity

```
 setContentView(R.layout.login_fragment);
```

You never seem to actually use LoginFragment class

I think you've loaded the wrong class because if you used `startActivity` on this activity code, your buttons would work fine

Comment: Of Course You Say True.

Comment: I can't solve a problem if I don't know what it is. And you should only comment if you have questions about this answer

Comment: I want to make a dependent spinner in android where data is comes on my sql server . I already make all of things. But i am not understand how can i make a Dependent . Please Help me this Topic

Comment: Not here. Post a separate question

Comment: My Id is not allowing me to ask a question can tell me how can i ask a question You

Comment: I will try out that but now where people say it, it seems to be clear.
@AshishShahi maybe you make your own post? It will help other people find it in the future and more people will read it and help you.

Comment: @Ashish Again, I'm sorry, but I'm not answering you here. Improve your reputation to ask questions more frequently, or wait. I'm sure I'm not the only person to solve the issue

Comment: Thanks For Your cooperation Bro .

Comment: @cricket_007
I tried it now and left the methods in the LoginActivity class, called the class from the fragment and put the setOnClickListener events into the LoginFragment but still nothing happens.

I will update the content in the main post to make it clear.

Comment: Called what class from what Fragment? You have no Fragment in the question

Comment: @cricket_007
I added it now. Btw, thank you very much for your efforts :-)

Comment: If you are actually loading that Fragment, you should get a nullpointerexception, so there is an error... Again, are you **sure** you're using Fragments and not just loading the exact same  XML layout into **an Activity**